# Is there a way to save H2O partial dependent plot results as a data frame?

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to create partial dependent plot using the following code

```
rf_pdp = rf_model .partial_plot(data = htest, cols = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], plot=True)
rf_pdp
```

Is there a way I can save the output such as mean_resp into a data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `partial_plot()` method returns a list where the elements are of type `h2o.two_dim_table.H2OTwoDimTable` or a list and a plot if you set the `plot` parameter = True (see the [api docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.partial_plot) to learn more about the parameters and return types).

to see this do:

```
type(rf_pdp) # should return a list
type(rf_pdp[0]) # should return h2o.two_dim_table.H2OTwoDimTable
```

Once you have selected the H2OTwoDimTable corresponding to the pdp column of interest you either select the "mean_response" column or you could convert the H2OTwoDimTable to a pandas dataframe and select the mean_resp from there.

So to get the mean_response column for "var1 " for example you can do

```
rf_pdp[0]["mean_response"]
```

or

```
rf_pdp[0].as_data_frame()['mean_response']
```

Comment: does that mean if I have 10 variables, I need use a loop to go through them then stack into one data frame?

Comment: i think it just depends on how you want to create you plot. you don't necessarily need to have one dataframe since you will be plotting a different line to represent the partial dependence of each feature against the target.

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible example:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(h2o, tidyverse, modeldata)

h2o.init()

# load HR data from modeldata pkg
data("attrition", package = "modeldata")

df <-
  attrition %>%
    mutate_if(
      .predicate = is.ordered,
      .funs.     = factor,
      ordered    = FALSE
    ) %>%
    mutate(
      Attrition  = factor(Attrition, levels = c("Yes", "No"))
    )

index <- 1:5

train.obs <- df[-index,]
loc.obs   <- df[index,]

# create h2o objects for modeling
y <- "Attrition"
x <- setdiff(names(train.obs), y)

train.obs.h2o <- as.h2o(train.obs)
loc.obs.h2o   <- as.h2o(loc.obs)

# create h2o RF model
h2o_rf <- h2o.randomForest(x, y, training_frame = train.obs.h2o)

# create Partial Dependence Plots (PDP)
h2o_pdp <-
  h2o.partialPlot(
    object = h2o_rf,
    data   = train.obs.h2o,
    cols.  = c("MonthlyIncome", "Age")
)
```

**Option 1:** Export pdp dataframe for each of `AGE` and `RACE` directly to **Excel** in separate named sheets

```
writexl::write_xlsx(
  list(
    MonthlyIncome = h2o_pdp[[1]],
    Age           = h2o_pdp[[2]]),
    path          = "pdp-metrics.xlsx"
)
```

**Option 2:** Store H2o PDP locally as dataframe object for each variable

```
pdpMonIncTbl <- as.data.frame(h2o_pdp[[1]])
pdpAgeTbl    <- as.data.frame(h2o_pdp[[2]])
```